# Auto pairing using strings instead of characters

Tags: vimscript, insert-mode, map-operator

I'm already aware of existing solution to automatically "surround" sentences/word/etc (eg: auto-surround, vim-surround, etc) but those (as far as i know) don't support using normal strings instead of characters (eg: {}, ()...).

I did found [this](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Automatically_append_closing_characters#Add_the_closing_brace_only_at_the_end_of_the_line) snippet which seems to do what i want:

```
function! ConditionalPairMap(open, close)
  let line = getline('.')
  let col = col('.')
  if col < col('$') || stridx(line, a:close, col + 1) != -1
    return a:open
  else
    return a:open . a:close . repeat("\<left>", len(a:close))
  endif
endf
inoremap <expr> ( ConditionalPairMap('(', ')')
inoremap <expr> { ConditionalPairMap('{', '}')
inoremap <expr> [ ConditionalPairMap('[', ']')
```

Only problem is that I'm not sure how to make this work with normal strings. Here what i tried using the above function:

```
inoremap <expr> ( ConditionalPairMap('te', '.te')
```

I mainly want to use those as custom "marker" or "header" for certain block of text. The above closing and opening marker are just example.

Additionally, I'm aware that by using normal or any string as either opening/closing surrounding will be confusing when writing normal text, that's why I'd prefer if it would only trigger the closing marker when there a newline in front of it, like so:

```
te # no newline yet
```

If there a newline after it, place the closing after it:

```
te #a newline placed here
.te
```

PS: This is mainly to be used in `Insert mode`.

Any way to do this?

Comment: Well, surround supports *some* string types (function calls, latex environments, xml tags, just to name a few), and lets you build your own.

Comment: I see. I already knew most of the surround plugins (especially the one by tpope) support xml/etc tags, but I don't think his or other ones exist with support for "custom" ones? (eg: like the one in my example). Feel free to correct me if there is any support for that of course :) @D.BenKnoble

Comment: https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround/blob/f51a26d3710629d031806305b6c8727189cd1935/doc/surround.txt#L151

Comment: It's hard to cover this topic in a too generic way, since often details change the experience significantly... If what you're after could be narrowed to "insert closing tag in its own line when pressing Enter on a line beginning with the open tag", then something like this might work: `inoremap <expr> <CR> getline('.') =~# '^\s*te\>' ? '<CR>.te<C-o>O' : '<CR>'`

Comment: Tried some example there with the plugin, such as `let g:surround_61 = "<%= \r %>"` but didn't work AFAIK. That said, I think even if it did, it wouldn't be "automatic", like with the example snippet i provided in my post (which does it automatically) @D.BenKnoble

Comment: YEP, that works great :D @filbranden Feel free to post this as answer if you want. Btw, any way to do this without necessarily using a regex? so i could use a different opening and closing string more easily. Otherwise, it's perfect

Comment: Your question also seems to mix up the vim-surround plug-in, which implements **Normal-mode** actions to surround existing contents, with plug-ins such as "auto-pairs" (and many others similar to it), which will add matching brackets while you insert them in **Insert-mode**. These are actually quite different from each other and have different trade offs... You mentioned "surround" at the top of your question, but your examples are much closer to what "auto-pairs" does...

Comment: Nice! I'll post that as an answer. Let me look into making it more general to cover open/close tags from a Dict...

Comment: You're right, I'll edit this in. It was mostly as you said, since I always thought of "surrounding" a text element/block and "pairing" as the same thing...And i didn't mention i needed this in insert mode because I thought it was obvious given the snippet which use it (`inoremap`). @filbranden

Comment: lh-brackets supports auto-pairing of strings. It works in insert mode, and in visual and normal-mode for surrounding as well. And +1 to the separation of the insertion of the pair from the insertion of extra-lines on CR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're looking at pairing open/close tags across multiple lines (enclosing a block) and in your case it makes sense to insert the closing tag when breaking the line, my suggestion is to add a mapping to the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key in Insert mode and then use an `<expr>` to decide whether we need to add the closing tag. You can make that decision based on the contents of the current line, more specifically the first word you find on the line.

A very simple example for the exact case you described:

```
inoremap <expr> <CR> getline('.') =~# '^\s*te\>'
      \ ? '<CR>.te<C-o>O'
      \ : '<CR>'
```

It's using a regexp match on the current line to check whether the current line starts with `te`, possibly after some whitespace, then followed by a word boundary. In that case, it adds a `<CR>` to break the line, then adds the closing `.te`, and then uses the `<C-o>` sequence to enter Normal mode temporarily (`<Esc>` would have worked the same here), following by an `O` Normal-mode command, to insert a new line above the current one and start Insert mode there.

If the line doesn't start with the expected tag, then we simply insert a `<CR>`, to act as if there was no mapping for the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

You can extend this idea to define a Dictionary of pairs of open/close tags and use a function to look them up and match them. I'm posting an example below. It relies on the opening tags being a full word (followed by whitespace) on their own. But as this is Vimscript, you can decide to make it as complex as you wish, to cover corner cases that matter to you.

```
let g:tag_pairs = {
  \ 'te': '.te',
  \ 'if': 'endif',
  \ }

function! AddClosingPair()
  let firstword = get(split(getline('.')), 0)
  let closing = get(g:tag_pairs, firstword, '')
  if closing != ''
    return "\r".closing."\<C-o>O\<C-t>"
  endif
  return "\r"
endfunction

inoremap <expr> <CR> AddClosingPair()
```

Just update the `g:tag_pairs` Dictionary to cover more tag pairs. In this example, I also included an `\<C-t>` at the end of the sequence triggered by the tag pairs, to add indentation to the block opened by it. (That would be more appropriately handled in an `'indentexpr'`, but maybe it makes sense to keep it in your use case, so I included it.)

Comment: This is similar to what endwise (another tpope plugin) does. https://github.com/tpope/vim-endwise